# Launch coroutine from click event in fragment

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

What is the proper way to launch a coroutine from a click event that is defined in a fragment? From my understanding, `GlobalScope.launch` is used if you want to launch a coroutine that is supposed to remain in memory for the entire lifecycle of the app. But since a fragment usually has a shorter lifecycle than the app, `GlobalScope.launch` probably isn't the proper way. I assume that if I used `GlobalScope.launch`, it might keep the fragment from being garbage collected?

I really only need to launch the coroutine from a click event handler, which means that there is no parent functions that I would be calling from.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need a `job` to handle the coroutine cancelation to prevent leaks:

```
//inside Fragment
val job = Job()
val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + job)


//late in the button click

button.setOnClickListener{
  uiScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
    //asyncOperation
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
     //ui operation
   }

  }
}

//later in on destroy:

override fun onDestroy(){
  job.cancel()
  super.onDestroy()
}
```

You can also use [LifecycleScope extension](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope) from Google:

```
class MyFragment: Fragment() {
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            val params = TextViewCompat.getTextMetricsParams(textView)
            val precomputedText = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                PrecomputedTextCompat.create(longTextContent, params)
            }
            TextViewCompat.setPrecomputedText(textView, precomputedText)
        }
    }
}
```

Edit, in case you would re-fire another operation. Just use the same scope:

```
//let's assume you have a second button

button2.setOnClickListener{
  uiScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
    //perform second operation
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that if you don't call job.cancel when the fragment is destroyed, that the coroutine will keep that instance of the fragment alive?

Comment: Not the instance of the fragment, but the thread will remain unclosed

Comment: But if the fragment is destroyed, how can the thread stay unclosed, since it is bound to the fragment?

Comment: because any Android component runs on the *main* thread. While all the other threads you access you would need a way to close them after you have finished your work.

Comment: So in your solution, I suppose that each click event handler needs its own private CoroutineScope variable?

Comment: No, no. Use that `uiScope` to relaunch other coroutines. Let me edit the answer

Comment: But if the first click event hasn't finished its coroutine and you do a different click event that reuses the same coroutine, isn't that going to be a problem? I think your solution with LifecycleScope is probably the way to go.

Comment: well that depends on your use case. You can disable the button until the async operation is finished.

Comment: AsyncTasks were so easy to understand! So the block in lifecycleScope.launch{ runs in the MainThread unless you write withContext(...) ??? in that google example it sets UI stuff without needing to write withContext(Dispatchers.Main){

Answer (score 2):

> `GlobalScope.launch` is used if you want to launch a coroutine that is supposed to remain in memory for the entire lifecycle of the app.

This isn't necessarily so, it could be used for any coroutine that isn't coupled to an activity or phase of the app that the user could navigate away from. For example, you might launch a task that sends a one-way message to your server. It will probably finish quite soon, and you want it to finish whatever the user does later on.

> I assume that if I used `GlobalScope.launch`, it might keep the fragment from being garbage collected?

Only if the coroutine retains a reference to the fragment or a part of it, and only if it has the potential to run for a long time.

Specifically, the typical thing you do in an on-click event is perform some action that involves your back end (i.e., networking) and then updates the UI. Clearly this can take a long time (especially in case of bad network) and it retains a reference to the UI element it's going to touch later on. This should be bound to the lifecycle of the fragment.

> What is the proper way to launch a coroutine from a click event that is defined in a fragment?

The easiest way is like this, following the [official documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/):

```
class MyFragment : Fragment, CoroutineScope by MainScope {

    override fun onDestroy() {
        cancel() // extension on CoroutineScope
    }

    ... rest of your fragment code ...
}
```

This captures the idiom that you previously had to write by hand (as seen in the other answer here).

Answer (score 1):

```
class JobFragment : Fragment() {

    private val job = Job()
    private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + job)
    private var button : Button?= null
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_job, container, false)
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        button = view.findViewById(R.id.button)
        button?.setOnClickListener{
            uiScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
                val fun1 = async { followers1() }
                val fun2 = async { followers2() }
                Log.e("Test1", "${fun1.await()}", )
                Log.e("Test2", "${fun2.await()}", )
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                    //ui operation
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private fun followers1() {
        println("Followers Testing...")
    }
    private fun followers2() {
        println("Followers Testing...")
    }
    override fun onDestroy(){
        job.cancel()
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).